# How to show multiple viewholders in recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I tried to understand how I can easily tell two different views to be inflated depending on some information on the object...

My setup is like so but I keep crashing with this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
```

which points to this line:

```
myViewHolder.commentUsername.setTypeface(boldTypeface);
```

This is my adapter:

```
public class CommentsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<DatabaseComment> dbCommentsList;
    private DatabaseHelper db;
    private Context context;
    private Typeface typeFace, italicTypeface, boldTypeface;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public TextView commentUsername, commentUserMsg, commentUserDate, commentUserRemove;
        public ImageView emojiIcon;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            commentUsername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userAdapterUsername);
            commentUserMsg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.commentUserMsg);
            commentUserDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.commentUserDate);
            commentUserRemove = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.commentUserRemove);
            emojiIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.emojiIcon);
            Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "IN MY VIEW HOLDER");

            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            commentUserRemove.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mOnEntryClickListener != null) {
                Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "IN On click");
                mOnEntryClickListener.onEntryClick(v, getAdapterPosition());

            }
        }
    }
    private static OnEntryClickListener mOnEntryClickListener;

    public interface OnEntryClickListener {
        void onEntryClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public void setOnEntryClickListener(OnEntryClickListener onEntryClickListener) {
        mOnEntryClickListener = onEntryClickListener;
    }


    public class MyFeatureViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView commentCompany, commentCompanyMsg, commentCompanyDate;
        public ImageView emojiIcon;


            public MyFeatureViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
                commentCompany = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.commentCompany);
                commentCompanyMsg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.commentCompanyMsg);
                commentCompanyDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.commentCompanyDate);
                emojiIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.emojiIcon);
                Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "IN MY VIEW HOLDER");


        }


    }

    public CommentsAdapter(Context mContext, List<DatabaseComment> comments, Typeface myTypeface, Typeface myTypefaceItalic, Typeface myTypefaceBold) {
        context = mContext;
        db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        dbCommentsList = comments;
        typeFace = myTypeface;
        italicTypeface = myTypefaceItalic;
        boldTypeface = myTypefaceBold;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType){
            case 0:
                return new MyFeatureViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.comment_business_item, parent, false)); 
            case 1:
                return new MyFeatureViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.comment_user_item, parent, false));   
        }
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.comment_user_item, parent, false));


    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //int pos = getItemViewType(position);

        //is a business comment
        if(dbCommentsList.get(position).getIsType() == 0) {


            MyFeatureViewHolder featureViewHolder = (MyFeatureViewHolder) holder;

            DatabaseComment dbComment = dbCommentsList.get(position);

            featureViewHolder.commentCompany.setTypeface(boldTypeface);
            featureViewHolder.commentCompanyMsg.setTypeface(typeFace);
            featureViewHolder.commentCompanyDate.setTypeface(italicTypeface);

            featureViewHolder.commentCompany.setText(dbComment.getUsername());
            featureViewHolder.commentCompanyMsg.setText(dbComment.getCommentText());

            Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
            date.setTimeInMillis(dbComment.getCommentDate());
            String commentDateTxt = (date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "." + date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "." + date.get(Calendar.YEAR));

            featureViewHolder.commentCompanyDate.setText(commentDateTxt);


            //anything greater than 0 is a user comment
        } else {
            //TODO show x button near viewHolder if isChanged is 1

            MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;

            if(dbCommentsList.get(position).getIsChanged() == 1) {
                myViewHolder.commentUserRemove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                myViewHolder.commentUserRemove.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            DatabaseComment dbComment = dbCommentsList.get(position);

            myViewHolder.commentUsername.setTypeface(boldTypeface);
            myViewHolder.commentUserMsg.setTypeface(typeFace);
            myViewHolder.commentUserDate.setTypeface(italicTypeface);

            myViewHolder.commentUsername.setText(dbComment.getUsername());
            myViewHolder.commentUserMsg.setText(dbComment.getCommentText());

            Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
            date.setTimeInMillis(dbComment.getCommentDate());
            String commentDateTxt = (date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "." + date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "." + date.get(Calendar.YEAR));

            myViewHolder.commentUserDate.setText(commentDateTxt);

            int[] commentsImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_announcement_black_18dp, R.drawable.ic_announcement_black_18dp, R.drawable.ic_announcement_black_18dp, R.drawable.ic_explore_black_18dp};
            myViewHolder.emojiIcon.setImageResource(commentsImageList[dbComment.getIsType()]);



        }

        //grab more comments
        if(position > (dbCommentsList.size() - 3) && (dbCommentsList.size() % 20) == 0) {
            grabMoreComments();
        }

    }

    private void grabMoreComments() {
        //TODO
        //GRABAPI - OFFSET dbCommentsList.SIZE - IN LIMIT OF 20
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dbCommentsList.size();
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(dbCommentsList.get(position).getIsType() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This is my class where I setup the adapter:

```
private void setupAdapter() {
        commentsAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(this, dbCommentsList, TypeFaceProvider.getTypeFace(this, 0),
                TypeFaceProvider.getTypeFace(this, 1), TypeFaceProvider.getTypeFace(this, 2));
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        commentsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        commentsRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        //TODO CHECK THAT CLICKING ON COMMENT BY BUSINESS NOTHING HAPPENS

        commentsAdapter.setOnEntryClickListener(new CommentsAdapter.OnEntryClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEntryClick(View view, int position) {
                DatabaseComment comment = dbCommentsList.get(position);
                TextView deleteBtn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.commentUserRemove);
                if(view == deleteBtn) {

                    //used to remove the comment from db and the list
                    db.removeSingleComment(comment);
                    dbCommentsList.remove(position);
                    commentsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), comment.getUsername() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    takeToUserProfile(dbCommentsList.get(position));
                }
            }
        });




        commentsRecyclerView.setAdapter(commentsAdapter);

        commentsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

So in the adapter getItemViewType is not being done correctly... how do I say if the comments isType is 0 to show one view and anything else show the other view?

Comment: Check the condition in switch...return myViewHolder if the getViewType() returns 1. Later check whether the instance of holder is myViewHolder or not like if(holder instanceOf MyViewHolder) then update the views.

Comment: What do you mean by adding case: 1, I figured the default will return it, I tried with case:1 though as well and it still shows an error

Comment: that's fine, check the holder instance in onBindViewHolder().

Comment: You have to return viewType according to your conditions in `getItemViewType` of recycle view and change ViewHolder using switch case in `onCreateViewHolder`

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid How do I go about returning the viewType I figured returning a number would trigger the different switch cases in onCreateViewHolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error it looks like a view with id R.id.userAdapterUsername is missing in the layout file comment_user_item.xml

Comment: I am using the wrong id forgot to change it, did not realize, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First you need to override `getItemViewType` of your adapter like below: (I assume you can match your `viewholders` with your object's `getType()` method.)

```
@Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      return items.get(position).getType();
   }
```

And in your `onCreateViewHolder` method switch type and return your related viewholder.

```
     @Override
       public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
          View view = null;
          switch (viewType) {
              case ITEM_TYPE_A:
                  view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row_a, parent, false);
                  return new ATypeViewHolder(view);

              case ITEM_TYPE_B:
                  view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row_b, parent, false);
                  return new BTypeViewHolder(view);
    }
}
```

Inıt your adapter's `onBindViewHolder` method.

```
@Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         Item item = items.get(position);
         if(item != null){
              initializeViews(item, holder, position);
         }
}
```

Finally in your `initializeViews` method cast your viewholder according to your item type and use it:

```
private void initializeViews(final Item item, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
     swtich(item.gettype())
     {
        case ITEM_TYPE_A:
            ATypeViewHolder holder = (ATYpeViewHolder)viewHolder;
            // init your views

        case ITEM_TYPE_B:
            BTypeViewHolder holder = (BTypeViewHolder)viewHolder;
            // init your views.
     }
}
```

Not: Your viewholders must extend `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

I hope this'll help you. Good luck.

Comment: oh i'm sorry it's my private custom method. You should call it in onBindViewHolder method. I edited my post.

Comment: I see the methods you have but this does not change what I am doing in my own code, you are just adding another method outside of the onBindViewHolder that I am already doing within it?

Comment: Also, isType on the item can be 0 or greater than 0 ... so that is why I have to see if it is 0 if not return 1 (because the isType can be 0,1,2,3,4,etc...) but greater than 0 should inflate a different view.

Comment: I didn't review your code. I don't have time right now. i just answered how you can implement multiple type of viewholders in a recyclerview adapter. When i have time i'll review your code and answer your question.

Comment: Ok let me know when you do.

Comment: oke. if i forget please send me a message and let us discuss your problem.